# Sort Array with quick sort

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to sort an array in nonincreasing form.Element's of this array are 4 job profits.

so that profit[i] is profit of job i.I fill this array with user input that has no order.

I must use quick sort algorithm for this purpose.This algorithm sorts my array elements

correctly but i want to job numbers(array index for each job) sort with elements

concurrently.because i don't want to change job numbers.

Comment: So.... implement quick-sort ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: As usual ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I know quick sort algoritm well.All of things that i want is:

Comment: That's a hell of a cliff hanger.

Answer (score 4):

You could create `Job` objects that have `JobNumber` and `Profit` members, store them in an STL collection, and then sort the STL collection with [STL sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/).